# Missing RapidAPI application key (not missing)

Tags: javascript, typescript, post, postman, rapidapi

I am using rapidAPI.
When I POST (Postman) I get the message:

```
{
    "message": "Missing RapidAPI application key. Go to https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys to learn how to get your API application key."
}
```

The Problem is, that I have an RapidAPI aplication-key already in the POST

```
https://meetupdimashirokovv1.p.rapidapi.com/getEvents?x-rapidapi-host=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&x-rapidapi-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded&accessToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I have generated and tried out a new RapidAPI application key but it didn't work.

Comment: I can access the Meetup API directly. So the error occurs at the RapidAPI.

Answer (score 2):

RapidAPI supports passing the API key via a query parameter. You can do like this:

```
https://example.p.rapidapi.com/?rapidapi-key=***************************
```

Instead of this:

```
https://example.p.rapidapi.com/?x-rapidapi-key=***************************
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the x-RapidAPI-host and x-RapidAPI-key should not be in the HTTP parameter.
 since parameters specify the variable parts of your resources.

I also got this problem when I add the x-RapidAPI-host and x-RapidAPI-key in the params instead of in the headers.